# Show night / day icon (with php) using sunset / sunrise

Tags: php, html, date, date-sunrise

What is the best method / script to echo an image after sunset and before sunrise with php.

```
if (date("H:i") > date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 51.29, 4.49, 90.7, 2)) { $icon = "icon_night"; } else { $icon = "icon_day"; }
if (date("H:i") > date_sunrise(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 51.29, 4.49, 90.7, 2)) { $icon = "icon_night"; } else { $icon = "icon_day"; }

echo $icon;
```

I wanted to return a day and night icon.

Comment: are you saying the code above does not work? in what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing current time to each of sunrise / sunset independently meaning you'll get some odd results.

This should work for determining which one to show

```
$now = date("H:i");
$sunrise = date_sunrise(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 51.29, 4.49, 90.7, 2)
$sunset = date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 51.29, 4.49, 

$icon = ($now > $sunrise && $now < $sunset) ? 'icon_day' : icon_night'

// Will echo icon_day or icon_night
echo $icon;
```

Displaying an actual icon instead of text is a very different question. If that's what you're trying to get at more information is required (do you have icons? where are you showing them? what have you tried)

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you! And it's in a much easier way done.